# How to dynamically add some script code to the static header or footer of all pages in the frontend of opencart3

Tags: php, opencart-3

while creating a new module the challenge is, I have some script code i need to dynamically put it to all the pages in the frontend of opencart? how can we do this? 
Could you please help me to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using vQmod or OCMOD you would just hook on to some code from the header or footer template to output it.